# How to integrate CKFinder with Laravel?

Tags: php, session, laravel, ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm trying to integrate CKFinder with Laravel, and I'm about 95% there. I can get everything to work, except for the `CheckAuthentication` function - I have to make it `return true` regardless for the upload to work.

What I've tried doing is bootstrapping Laravel in the config.php file and then checking if a user is logged in, like below:

*public/packages/ckfinder/config.php*

```
<?php
/*
 * ### CKFinder : Configuration File - Basic Instructions
 *
 * In a generic usage case, the following tasks must be done to configure
 * CKFinder:
 *     1. Check the $baseUrl and $baseDir variables;
 *     2. If available, paste your license key in the "LicenseKey" setting;
 *     3. Create the CheckAuthentication() function that enables CKFinder for authenticated users;
 *
 * Other settings may be left with their default values, or used to control
 * advanced features of CKFinder.
 */

/** RIPPED FROM public/index.php **/

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader
| for our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll require it
| into the script here so that we do not have to worry about the
| loading of any our classes "manually". Feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../../../bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let's turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight these users.
|
*/

$app = require __DIR__.'/../../../bootstrap/start.php';

/** END public/index.php **/

/**
 * This function must check the user session to be sure that he/she is
 * authorized to upload and access files in the File Browser.
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
function CheckAuthentication()
{
    // WARNING : DO NOT simply return "true". By doing so, you are allowing
    // "anyone" to upload and list the files in your server. You must implement
    // some kind of session validation here. Even something very simple as...

    return Auth::check();
}
```

This always returns false, though. I've also tried directly using Laravel's `Session` to set a variable to true when someone logs in, and false when they log out, and then checking that in the config.php file, but it always returns the default value in `Session::get("IsAuthorized", false);`. Can anyone offer some guidance as to -

1) How to authenticate whether the user should be allowed to upload?

2) Why bootstrapping Laravel in another file seems to cause it to use a separate session, even when it's loading the same files?

Comment: maybe this post can help you (http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=11909)

Comment: Check the official [CKFinder package for Laravel 5.5+](https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package) - hopefully this will make the integration easier.

Answer (score 1):

I tried integrating simogeo's Filemanager and KCFinder into a Laravel project and I found the same problem.

With this code, it's possible to share Laravel's session and check authentication from external projects:

https://gist.github.com/frzsombor/ddd0e11f93885060ef35

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, starting from 4.1.28, Application::boot() does not initialize sensitive session data anymore.

So if you're integrating 3rd party library, which needs external authentification check through sessions, simple checking Auth::check() will not work. However, we can still use old $_SESSION variable.

E.g. this one will not work:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
$app->boot();
return Auth::check();
```

Session variables for Auth::check() to work are initialized only in $app->run() sequence. But in that case, routing will take place and probably you will get unrecognized page... unless you're using dedicated Laravel package for this.

This one - below - still works:

```
// Somewhere in your app - e.g. in filters.php, "auth"/"guest" filters declaration
if (session_id() == '') {
    @session_start();
    /* or Session:start(); */
}
$_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = Auth::check() ? true : false;
```

Then in your case, function would be simple as:

```
function CheckAuthentication()
{
    if (session_id() == '') {
        @session_start();
    }
    return isset( $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] ) && $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] == true;
}
```

N.B. If you can use Ajax calls for authorization checks, you can still make a custom API with JSON request to user-logged (as an example) to see if user is authentificated.

To answer your second question - it's not so simple as it sounds. Laravel, as a default, uses file system for session storage. While session data is still accessible, it is encrypted - unless you will write your own Session manager, you can't extract anything from there easily.

Comment: It is possible for laravel5.3?