# laravel standard php files on public directory

Tags: session, laravel, integration

Due to some integration with some external php scripts(http://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager). I need to get access to laravel classes, inside public directory php files. For example, i have created: public/test.php with the code:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
$app->boot(); //??
echo Auth::check();
echo Auth::user()->username; //ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object 
?>
```

I dont want to do the $app->run() that redirects the process/request to the Laravel Request Lifecycle.
I need access to user information or laravel session values.

Thanks

Comment: i have resolve the problem by using php session along side with laravel session to share data. see solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24125565/1863603,